# How can we display an image (offline) as an action from QR Code scanning?

Tags: php, android

QS- I am an unable to create an QR CODE which will display an image as a result of QR code scanning (Without Internet or external link). I am able to  to create link,show business card,call a phone number etc as result of QR code in PHP or android. Is it possible show an image directly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own client scanner; that would be possible by base64-encoding the image and decode it in the client.
If you rely on third party scanners; I don't know if there's a standard for it but I haven't seen it before.